# Sonarqube Authentication Failure

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

I'm having a confusing problem with SonarQube 5.6 when trying to run an analysis with the sonar-maven-plugin 3.2 on a Java 8/Maven 3 project.

The error message is the following:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin: 3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project YYY: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to download libraries from server: Status returned by url [XXX/sonarqube/batch_bootstrap/index] is not valid: [401] -> [Help 1]

The account I'm using has the permission "Execute Analysis" (it's in the group sonar-administrators) and the credentials are working when logging in via browser. Even the connection test of the SonarLint Eclipse plug-in was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to reach the SonarQube server using an external URL instead of a local one. Seems to have to do with HTTPS or something like this. Using the local URL (http://sonarqube:9000/sonarqube) it now works.